# How does single-sided deafness affect the different pilot licenses?

Tags: medical, student-pilot, pilot-certification, germany

About 12 and a half years ago I lost the sense of hearing in my left ear due to borreliosis. However, I have always wanted to get a pilot's license at some point in my life. I am aware that for some (or even all?) licenses, a medical examination must be passed and one-sided hearing loss is essentially a no-go.

So my question is: What are my possibilities with my disability? What kind of license could I still be allowed to get or will I have to bury this dream?

I live in Germany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were willing to travel to the US (which is not all that uncommon to get a pilots license) and get your license under the FAA regulations you could do it as per the regulations,

> **[§67.305   Ear, nose, throat, and equilibrium. Ear, nose, throat, and
>   equilibrium standards for a third-class airman medical certificate
>   are:](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=b0859a44f58f555dbdc7660c19c131c6&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.5.4.1.3&idno=14)**
>
> (a) The person shall demonstrate acceptable hearing by **at least one** of
>   the following tests:
>
> (1) Demonstrate an ability to hear an average conversational voice in
>   a quiet room, using both ears, at a distance of 6 feet from the
>   examiner, with the back turned to the examiner.
>
> (2) **Demonstrate an acceptable understanding of speech as determined by
>   audiometric speech discrimination testing to a score of at least 70
>   percent *obtained in one ear or in a sound field environment*.**
>
> (3) Provide acceptable results of pure tone audiometric testing of
>   unaided hearing acuity according to the following table of worst
>   acceptable thresholds, using the calibration standards of the American
>   National Standards Institute, 1969:

The way this is written if you can score at least 70% in one ear on the audiometric speech discrimination test you should be good to go. Note this is for a class 3 medical with will not allow you to fly commercial operations. I am not sure how the new basic med requirements fall into all this but your best if you have specific questions is to contact an [AME directly](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/amelocator/).

From a practical standpoint, the cockpit of most small planes is fairly defining already and the headsets take mono signals from the radios so I don't really see how the lack of binaural hearing would present any issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is already very helpful and encouraging! However, I just read that I will not be able to fly D-registered airplanes with it and would probably have to fly N-registered planes ([Link](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/flying-in-europe-with-faa-cert.59773/#post-1172402)). Of course, I will be able to convert it to the German PPL(A), but I am not sure, if I have to get a medical re-evaluation. I did write to a local medical examiner, though, as you advised. Thanks!

Comment: @basseur I belive you can fly and more importantly have an N-Registered aircraft in Europe. I belive there are some questions around it on here somewhere.

Comment: Alright, I will look into it. Thanks again!